# flatten list by replacing comma with plus operator inside a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic, flatten

I am working on a scenario in Prolog (eclipse) wherein I need a list structure to be reformatted.

I have a list of the form:

```
MyList = [a,b,c].
```

I was trying to see if I can flatten the list to a single element with all the commas replaced with the + operator.

So my result list would look like:

```
ResultList = [a+b+c]
```

which is a single element list. The length of the initial list is arbitrary.

I know prolog is not suited for such operations, but can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here it is, in standard Prolog. I think there should be no difference with Eclipse:

```
list_to_op([X,Y|T], [R]) :-
    list_to_op(T, X+Y, R).
```

**edit**: bug noted by false

```
list_to_op([X], [X]).

list_to_op([X], R, R+X).
list_to_op([X|T], R, Q) :-
    list_to_op(T, R+X, Q).
```

test:

```
?- list_to_op([a,b,c],X).
X = [a+b+c] .
```

The accumulator is required to give the appropriate associativity: the simpler and more intuitive definition

```
list_to_op1([X], X).
list_to_op1([X|R], X+T) :-
   list_to_op1(R, T).
```

gives

```
?- list_to_op1([a,b,c],X).
X = a+ (b+c) .
```

If evaluation order is important, use list_to_op.

**edit**:
there is a bug: list_to_op([a,b],X) fails.

here the correction, as often happens, it's a simplification:

```
list_to_op([], R, R).
list_to_op([X|T], R, Q) :-
    list_to_op(T, R+X, Q).
```

Comment: @chac `list_to_op([3],Op)` fails. Intended?

Comment: @chac: I'd rather write `list_to_op([X],X).`

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
flatten_list(A,[B]) :- flatten_list_inner(A,B).

flatten_list_inner([A],A).
flatten_list_inner([H|T],H+Y) :- flatten_list_inner(T,Y).
```

The output is slightly different from what you wanted. It is currently [a + (b + c)]

Comment: Almost the same (apart from predicate and argument names) as something I wrote and used this past couple of months.  Since + is an infix operator, when the compound terms from **flatten_list_inner/2** are written, those pesky parentheses appear.  But such terms can be evaluated by **is/2** (if atoms a,b,c are replaced by numbers).

Answer (score 0):

How about this non-recursive version..

```
list_to_op(L, Res) :-
    concat_atom(L, '+', Atom),
    Res = [Atom].


?-  list_to_op([a,b,c], X).
X = ['a+b+c'].
```

Edit: This works in Swi-prolog.. not sure about Eclipse.